# Setup maker for visual studio solutions

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have 4-5 solutions of visual studio 2008. I want to build a setup.exe that can install these applications and services on clients machine. Also, I want the setup to be customizable like which applications to install, where to install, license agreement screen, progress bar, etc. Something like the installer which we see while installing the Visual Studio 2008 IDE.

Any idea about any free version of it ?

Comment: Which version of Visual studio are you using? The Express Edition is able to generate ClickOnce setups, the higher versions can generate setup projects that can do lots of this stuff.

Comment: VS 2008 Professional Edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, there are setup projects which come with visual studio - [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/717cfce0-3061-400f-9ea3-069f73f3a473) is an extensive FAQ.

There are also many third party installers:

- [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/) has a very good reputation.
- The [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) toolset is also quite popular.
- [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) is also a popular installer.

Comment: Are all of them free or commercial. Will check it out them :)